# How to make a usb autoplay when plugged in

Tags: audio, usb, autorun

I'm able to autorun an `icon` file from USB flash drive, but am unable to figure out how to autorun a music file.

I've tried the following code without success.

Specifically, the `open` option doesn't work.

```
[AUTORUN]
Icon = Pixelmixer-Basic-2-User-anonymous.ico
open = Courtesy Call - Thousand Foot Krutch (Lyrics).mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, autorun doesn't work anymore, due to security concerns.

It was far too easy to launch malicious applications this way.